# Rename many *.pdf files with their respective Contents-Title

Tags: windows

I have many(around 500) pdf files having useless names, so i want to rename all of them with their respective 'Title' of files. 'Title' here refers to the heading(top most title with largest font size) of file/document, when it is opened in reading mode.
I want to achieve this by some program/script or manually consisting of few steps only in Window7.So please help...

**EDIT:**
I have done nothing to achieve this, but was thinking that, there can be some script or software, which will read the text of pdf file and find the text having largest font, then can use the largest-font-sized-text as new name for renaming the file.So i mainly just need the way to find the largest-font-sized-text present in pdf file.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Any code!!!

Answer (score 11):

i have found this free software:
http://www.advancedrenamer.com/ 
that allows you to rename mass pdf files with their metatags.

[image: how to rename pdf with their metatag]

Comment: What a fantastic tool. I see this was posted in 2014. It's still helping people out in 2022.

Answer (score 4):

If these are pdfs of academic articles you can use Mendeley - it is a free program, which runs under Windows. You can drop all the pdfs in a folder and select how you want them renamed - e.g. title-year-author. It works very well for recent pdfs, however, it has some trouble with older articles. But then it will flag them as incomplete records that can be manually renamed.

http://www.mendeley.com/

Answer (score 2):

There is also [pdf-title-rename.py](https://github.com/jdmonaco/pdf-title-rename), a simple Python script to batch rename PDF files with their (sanitized) title.

Answer (score 0):

[Zotero](https://www.zotero.org) (free/[opensource](https://github.com/zotero)) and [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) (used to be awesome; ruined by Elsevier) do exactly this auto-renaming of PDFs by default.

Simply drag/drop all PDF files on the main window of one of these programs.
Few seconds later the PDFs will be renamed automatically according to their respective real title extracted from the content (metadata, to be more precise).

Please note that both of these programs were designed for academic documents, therefore, the default format of automatic renaming function might not suite your purpose out of the box (e.g., title-author-year.pdf) however, one can easily customize that under "settings".

> **Automatic renaming** (Zotero)
>
> When PDFs are added to existing Zotero items or metadata is retrieved for a PDF, Zotero will now automatically rename the file based on the parent metadata. This applies to both linked and stored files. A future version of Zotero will provide additional options for customizing the naming format.
> You can disable automatic renaming from the General pane of the preferences. (Files saved along with items from web translators have always been automatically renamed and aren’t affected by this setting.)
> [[ref](https://www.zotero.org/blog/zotero-5-0-36/)]

[image]
[source and more](https://iupui.libguides.com/Mendeley/tipstricks)

> **File Organizer** (Mendeley)
>
> Once again, Mendeley has considered this situation and provides an effortless way to organize your files with a built-in feature called: ‘File Organizer’.
> As the name suggests, this feature can organize your files for you in a few different ways. You can store your files in a centralized folder with all the files renamed to a specific format. The format is easy to customize by simply dragging the naming categories from one input box to the other. [[ref](https://blog.mendeley.com/2010/04/06/an-organized-folder-is-a-sign-of-a-file-organizer/)]

Comment: Does this allow selection of a folder only and not the entire references in the Mendeley?